# Change Width of Dynamic Data List Display

Tags: java, list, dynamic, width, liferay

I am trying to change the width of the Dynamic Data List Display in Spreadsheet View in Liferay Portal.
In the non-spreadsheet view the list is as wide as the screen, but with the spreadhseet view boolean selected, the list has a predetermined fixed width.
Does anyone know how I can change this to a percentage to take advantage of the full screen instead of the 700 and something pxs it comes predetermined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create hook plugin and override

`/html/portlet/dynamic_data_lists/view_spreadsheet_records.jsp`

In that file find something like

```
A.Plugin.DataTableScroll,
{
    height: 700,
    width: 900,
}
```

and change it to

```
A.Plugin.DataTableScroll,
{
    height: 700,
    width: A.one('#<portlet:namespace />dataTable').width()
}
```

At the end of file put

```
<style>#<portlet:namespace />dataTableContent table {width: 100%;}</style>
```

**Note** that if you set `width: "100%"` than your grid container will never get it's own scrollbar and you would have horizontal scrollbar for complete page, which does not work well with control panel pages.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Do you know how I can add format or some kind of formula to certain columns?

Comment: You are welcome. I have never played with Liferay's AUI (nor with YUI) but as it is based on Yahoo's YUI you could take a look at http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/#formatters. I think that you can add configuration to the same file (from the answer, beneath height and width properties).

Comment: I'm trying to add a progress bar to one of the columns for each row, like let's say I enter number 50 (for 50%) it should give me a progress bar colored to 50% instead of displaying number 50, does that make sense?